# sorting array of tuple in haskell by index

Tags: sorting, haskell

I write  a code to sort index of tuple list  I try to use **map** with `bubblesort()`
to avoid using **loops**

```
     bubblesort::(Ord t) => [t]->[t]
     bubblesort[x,y,z,xs]=
                if x<y then x : map bubblesort [y,z,xs]
                       else y : map bubblesort [x,z,xs]
```

but it give me an error that :

```
ERROR line 20 - Type error in list
*** Expression     : [y,xs]
*** Term           : xs
*** Type           : [a]
*** Does not match : a
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type
```

*note please give me instruction only

--The complier is online compiler

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Just sort a list, or sort a tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you're having is one which I see beginners make all the time. You're using a list, so you've decided that you have to use square brackets. What you really need is something like:

```
bubblesort (x:y:xs) = 
    if x < y 
       then x : bubblesort (y:xs)
       else y : bubblesort (x:xs)
```

when you use something like

```
foo [a,b,c] = …
```

You're explicitly pattern matching on a list with *exactly* three elements. If you use

```
foo (a:b:c:xs) = …
```

then you're explicitly matching on a list with *at least* three elements, where the first is bound to the name a, the second b, the third c, and the rest of the list (no matter how long it is) is called xs.

I hope that helps clear it up. It's a very common mistake.

Comment: This does fix part of his problem, but you'll also need the recursive base cases for `bubblesort a:[]` and `bubblesort []`.

Comment: @eternalmatt right, I didn't want to do all their homework for them =)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the full solution to this but bubblesort expects `[t]`, but `bubblesort [x,z,xs]` would be a function of `[[t]] -> [[t]]`. So each time, the type gets wrapped around another `[]`

Also, you wouldn't need to do `map bubblesort`. Try to remember what the `map` function does exactly to see why this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Glad I could help without giving too much away :)

Comment: I don't think this answers the real problem at all. See my comment below for what I believe does solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Thanx alote etemalmatt this my slve for my own problem

```
  bubbleSort::(Ord t) => [t]->[t]
  bubbleSort[x,y,z,xs]=
                if x<y then x : [y,z,xs]
                       else y : [x,z,xs]
   superBubble::(Ord t) => [[t]]->[[t]]
   superBubble a=map bubbleSort a
```

my problem was to use `map` with function that applied recursively to all element so my solution is to made it work with one element as you see in `bubbleSort()` now it fixed

Comment: This will only work on four-element lists, which is probably not what you want, but it's getting closer. You might want to ask about this on the IRC channel so you can go back and forth with someone and get it to do what you want, step by step.

Comment: The #haskell IRC channel on Freenode. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info for more information about that (and several other Haskell resources).